# Writing a custom nss hosts module

Tags: glibc, nss

I'm seeking to implement a custom `nss` module for the `getent hosts` lookup. Based on glibc's `resolv/nss-dns/dns-host.c` and gnunet's `src/gns/nss/nss_gns.c` I wrote the following minimal implementation that I hoped at *least* should write something to syslog - which it sadly *doesn't*.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <nss.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#define _nss_lash_gethostbyname2_r _nss_lash_gethostbyname_r
#define _nss_lash_gethostbyname3_r _nss_lash_gethostbyname_r
#define _nss_lash_gethostbyname4_r _nss_lash_gethostbyname_r
#define _nss_lash_getcanonname_r _nss_lash_gethostbyaddr_r
#define _nss_lash_gethostbyaddr2_r _nss_lash_gethostbyaddr_r
#define _nss_lash_getnetbyname_r _nss_lash_gethostbyaddr_r
#define _nss_lash_getnetbyaddr_r _nss_lash_gethostbyaddr_r

typedef char addr[1]; 
const addr default_addrs[2] = {0x01, 0x00};

enum nss_status
_nss_lash_gethostbyname_r (const char *name, struct hostent *result,
              char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop,
              int *h_errnop)
{
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, name);
    if (!strcmp(name, "lash")) {
        return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
    }
    *(result->h_aliases) = 0x0;
    result->h_addrtype = AF_INET;
    result->h_length = 1;
    *(result->h_addr_list) = (char *)default_addrs;
    *errnop = 0;
    *h_errnop = NETDB_SUCCESS; 
    return NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS;      
}

enum nss_status
_nss_lash_gethostbyaddr_r (const char *name, struct hostent *result,
              char *buffer, size_t buflen, int *errnop,
              int *h_errnop)
{
    syslog(LOG_ERR, name);
    if (!strcmp(name, "lash")) {
        return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
    }
    *(result->h_aliases) = 0x0;
    result->h_addrtype = AF_INET;
    result->h_length = 1;
    *(result->h_addr_list) = (char *)default_addrs;
    *errnop = 0;
    *h_errnop = NETDB_SUCCESS; 
    return NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS;      

}
```

I've added `lash` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. `strace` shows that the `/lib/libnss_lash.so.2` file is being successfully opened. However the return value from the `nss` lookup is `NSS_UNAVAIL` / `ENOENT`. If I add `[unavail=return]` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf` after the `lash` entry, I get the same result.

Anyone have any clues to what I'm missing?

(the `#define` lines attempt to catch all symbols found in `objdump -T /lib/libnss_dns.so`, which seems to be the simpler implementation)

Using:

- `glibc 2.30`
- `gnunet 0.11.6-ish`
- `nss 3.49.2`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you described. Using your code, I get the syslog output when invoking `gethostbyname_r` from another program. glibc-2.31, nss-3.53, no gnunet. I don't get your comment about the `#define` statements. Since `#define` is only a pre-processor directive, these statements do not actually add any code to your program (check with `nm -g libnss_lash.so.2`). But also, those functions have different signatures (e.g. gethostbyname2_r takes a different number of arguments than gethostbyname_r), so I don't see how you could define one as a simple alias for the other.

Comment: Also I assume the `!strcmp(name, "lash")` part is on purpose, i.e. when name is **equal to** `lash` you want to return `NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write to syslog from the NSS module, you need to open the syslog first of all. Here is an example:

```
openlog(NSS_MODULE_NAME, LOG_PID | LOG_CONS, LOG_AUTHPRIV);

syslog(LOG_ERR, "Something wrong here. ERROR: %s", error_str);

syslog(LOG_INFO, "Some info: %s", info_str);

closelog();
```

And don't forget to close it at the end. Good luck! =)